# How can I print directly from a screenshot in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: printing, screenshot

my laptop is running ubuntu 20.04

I would like to be able to take a screenshot of a specific area of the screen and print it directly from the screenshot tool so that I do not have to save it and print it from another tool. Currently I save the screenshot and then run gimp to print it.

Is printing the screenshot without saving possible ?

Comment: gnome-screenshot -f, --file=filename.png            Save screenshot directly to this file
then find some command line to print images
lp -o landscape -o fit-to-page -o media=A4 filename.png
https://askubuntu.com/questions/749334/print-using-lpr-command-how-to-print-without-scaling
then make a shortcut key to do both

Answer (score 0):

The closest I have come to this is to have the screenshot saved to memory, open Gimp, and print.

1. Take a screenshot of a region with: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd>
   ***Note:** This saves the screenshot to memory.*
2. Bring up the application search bar: <kbd>Super</kbd>
3. Type: "Gimp" (or just "Gi" for me, as there are no other applications that start that way)
4. Paste: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
5. Print: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
6. Close Gimp: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>

The entire process takes about 5 seconds and, fortunately, it's not something I need to do too often.

I wonder if this could be semi-automated with `xdotool` ...

Answer (score 0):

After taking the screenshot run this command, it pastes clipboard to a temporary file and then opens it your browser (works with Chrome and Brave):

```
xclip -selection clipboard -o -t image/png >/tmp/clipboard.png && google-chrome /tmp/clipboard.png 2>/dev/null
```

`2>/dev/null` is to suppress spurious `libva` error.